# Hungarian characters in Firebird database

Tags: firebird, firebird2.1

I cannot seem to get Hungarian accented characters to store properly in my Firebird database despite using ISO8859_2 character set and ISO_HUN collation.

This string for example:

> Magyar Képzőművészeti Egyetem, Festő szak, mester: Klimó Károly

gets displayed as

> Magyar Képzomuvészeti Egyetem, Festo szak, mester: Klimo Karoly

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's a bit weird that `ó` and `á` are stripped as well: those should be in latin1 as well (to which latin2 usually falls back)

Comment: You need to provide more information: what is your connection character set, what is the column character set, how are you getting and storing the data, and how are you retrieving and displaying the data?

Comment: Connection is ISO8859_2 as is column character set. I am just using IBEXPERT.

Comment: Interesting, what happens if you do something like `select 'Képzőművészeti' from RDB$DATABASE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string is UTF8 encoded. It's working fine with IBExpert and an UTF8 database. Make sure that you're using the correct character set (DB connection, DB column, string).